# Terraform: IAM role error while attaching multiple target group with an AWS ECS service

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I am trying to create an AWS ECS Service with multiple target groups. The service was already created with a custom IAM role but I tried to attach a second target group which leads it to recreate the service.

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "sampple" {
  name            = "sample"
  cluster         = var.ecs_cluster_id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.sample.arn
  desired_count   = var.desired_count
  # iam_role                           = var.ecs_role
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 70

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.webapp.id
    container_name   = "nginx"
    container_port   = 80
  }

  dynamic "load_balancer" {
    for_each = var.private_endpoint
    content {
      target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.private_endpoint.0.id
      container_name   = "nginx"
      container_port   = 80
    }
  }
}
```

Plan:

```
  + resource "aws_ecs_service" "webapp" {
      + cluster                            = "arn:aws:ecs:region:acccount-id:cluster/im-staging0"
      + deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
      + deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 70
      + desired_count                      = 1
      + enable_ecs_managed_tags            = false
      + iam_role                           = "ecsServiceRole"
      + id                                 = (known after apply)
      + launch_type                        = (known after apply)
      + name                               = "webapp"
      + platform_version                   = (known after apply)
      + scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
      + task_definition                    = (known after apply)

      + load_balancer {
          + container_name   = "nginx"
          + container_port   = 80
          + target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:acccount-id:targetgroup/im-staging-app-alb-tg/81129f7bc760e5e9"
        }
      + load_balancer {
          + container_name   = "nginx"
          + container_port   = 80
          + target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:acccount-id:targetgroup/im-staging-webapp-alb-tg/b6a756a7c06a2054"
        }

      + placement_strategy {
          + field = (known after apply)
          + type  = (known after apply)
        }
    }
}
```

Initial Plan Diff:

```
  # module.webapp.aws_ecs_service.webapp must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_ecs_service" "sample" {
        cluster                            = "arn:aws:ecs:region:account-id:cluster/sample"
        deployment_maximum_percent         = 200
        deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 70
        desired_count                      = 1
        enable_ecs_managed_tags            = false
      - health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 0 -> null
        iam_role                           = "ecsServiceRole"
      ~ id                                 = "arn:aws:ecs:region:account-id:service/webapp" -> (known after apply)
      ~ launch_type                        = "EC2" -> (known after apply)
        name                               = "webapp"
      + platform_version                   = (known after apply)
      - propagate_tags                     = "NONE" -> null
        scheduling_strategy                = "REPLICA"
      - tags                               = {} -> null
      ~ task_definition                    = "arn:aws:ecs:region:account-id:task-definition/im-staging-webapp:1968" -> (known after apply)

      - deployment_controller {
          - type = "ECS" -> null
        }

        load_balancer {
            container_name   = "nginx"
            container_port   = 80
            target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:region:account-id:targetgroup/im-staging0-webapp-alb-tg/b6a756a7c06a2054"
        }
      + load_balancer { # forces replacement
          + container_name   = "nginx"
          + container_port   = 80
          + target_group_arn = (known after apply)
        }

      + placement_strategy {
          + field = (known after apply)
          + type  = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
 InvalidParameterException: You cannot specify an IAM role for services that require a service linked role.
    status code: 400, request id: 514323ae-f95c-4dee-87d4-9647d2078c50 "webapp"
```

It normally works if I remove the iam_role parameter from the resource.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the plan?

Comment: That's showing is creating it from scratch, not recreating it (a destroy followed by a create ). It sounds like you no longer have that resource in your state file. Can you edit the question further to show a plan where it doesn't replace it and then the diff in the code that then leads to the plan that is in your question?